# How can I find a specific portion of a program within a hex dump?

Tags: assembly, exe, hexdump, i386, hex-editors

If I am looking at a section of assembly code disassembled in PE Explorer how can I find that section of the program in a hex dump within HxD? I need to modify the program flow.

I may not be using the appropriate software. I can post any additional information necessary to help me proceed.

I have disassembled the .exe with PE Explorer. I have used HxD to view the hex dump. Using PE Explorer, I believe have identified the section of the program that performs the check for an external monitor among other things and either throws an error or proceeds through the program. I need to bypass the external monitor check.

I am trying to roll back the firmware on a Dell K10A docking station. The problem is the firmware expects an external monitor to be connected to the dock. However, the external monitor ports are not working on this dock. This is a common problem with these docks directly related to a Dell firmware upgrade that bricks the dock.

```
// 00403B6E  CCCC                           Align   4
// 00403B70                           SUB_L00403B70:
// 00403B70  55                             push    ebp
// 00403B71  8BEC                           mov ebp,esp
// 00403B73  6AFF                           push    FFFFFFFFh
// 00403B75  68F81B5500                     push    L00551BF8
// 00403B7A  64A100000000                   mov eax,fs:[00000000h]
// 00403B80  50                             push    eax
// 00403B81  83EC14                         sub esp,00000014h
// 00403B84  A1509F5A00                     mov eax,[L005A9F50]
// 00403B89  33C5                           xor eax,ebp
// 00403B8B  8945F0                         mov [ebp-10h],eax
// 00403B8E  56                             push    esi
// 00403B8F  57                             push    edi
// 00403B90  50                             push    eax
// 00403B91  8D45F4                         lea eax,[ebp-0Ch]
// 00403B94  64A300000000                   mov fs:[00000000h],eax
// 00403B9A  8BF9                           mov edi,ecx
// 00403B9C  E84C3D0000                     call    SUB_L004078ED
// 00403BA1  33D2                           xor edx,edx
// 00403BA3  8BC8                           mov ecx,eax
// 00403BA5  85C9                           test    ecx,ecx
// 00403BA7  0F95C2                         setnz   dl
// 00403BAA  85D2                           test    edx,edx
// 00403BAC  750A                           jnz L00403BB8
// 00403BAE  6805400080                     push    80004005h
// 00403BB3  E818DCFFFF                     call    SUB_L004017D0
// 00403BB8                           L00403BB8:
// 00403BB8  8B01                           mov eax,[ecx]
// 00403BBA  FF500C                         call    [eax+0Ch]
// 00403BBD  83C010                         add eax,00000010h
// 00403BC0  8945E0                         mov [ebp-20h],eax
// 00403BC3  8D45E4                         lea eax,[ebp-1Ch]
// 00403BC6  50                             push    eax
// 00403BC7  C745FC00000000                 mov dword ptr [ebp-04h],00000000h
// 00403BCE  FF1544325500                   call    [KERNEL32.dll!GetSystemPowerStatus]
// 00403BD4  85C0                           test    eax,eax
// 00403BD6  7511                           jnz L00403BE9
// 00403BD8  6A3C                           push    0000003Ch
// 00403BDA  6878605800                     push    SWC00586078_Error__Unable_to_read_system_pow
// 00403BDF  8D4DE0                         lea ecx,[ebp-20h]
// 00403BE2  E819070000                     call    SUB_L00404300
// 00403BE7  EB3C                           jmp L00403C25
// 00403BE9                           L00403BE9:
// 00403BE9  F645E401                       test    byte ptr [ebp-1Ch],01h
// 00403BED  7514                           jnz L00403C03
// 00403BEF  68DF000000                     push    000000DFh
// 00403BF4  68F8605800                     push    SWC005860F8_Error___Power_not_detected_on_th
// 00403BF9  8D4DE0                         lea ecx,[ebp-20h]
// 00403BFC  E8FF060000                     call    SUB_L00404300
// 00403C01  EB22                           jmp L00403C25
// 00403C03                           L00403C03:
// 00403C03  E8F8FAFFFF                     call    SUB_L00403700
// 00403C08  85C0                           test    eax,eax
// 00403C0A  7433                           jz  L00403C3F
// 00403C0C  8D4DE0                         lea ecx,[ebp-20h]
// 00403C0F  83F812                         cmp eax,00000012h
// 00403C12  7507                           jnz L00403C1B
// 00403C14  68B8625800                     push    SWC005862B8_Error__Tablet_display_is_not_set
// 00403C19  EB05                           jmp L00403C20
// 00403C1B                           L00403C1B:
// 00403C1B  68E8635800                     push    SWC005863E8_Error__Tablet_cannot_detect_exte
// 00403C20                           L00403C20:
// 00403C20  E8AB030000                     call    SUB_L00403FD0
// 00403C25                           L00403C25:
// 00403C25  8B75E0                         mov esi,[ebp-20h]
// 00403C28  56                             push    esi
// 00403C29  8D8FD4060000                   lea ecx,[edi+000006D4h]
// 00403C2F  E820F00100                     call    SUB_L00422C54
// 00403C34  8BCE                           mov ecx,esi
// 00403C36  E8B5DAFFFF                     call    SUB_L004016F0
// 00403C3B  33FF                           xor edi,edi
// 00403C3D  EB35                           jmp L00403C74
// 00403C3F                           L00403C3F:
// 00403C3F  688C5A5800                     push    L00585A8C
// 00403C44  8D8FD4060000                   lea ecx,[edi+000006D4h]
// 00403C4A  E805F00100                     call    SUB_L00422C54
// 00403C4F  6A5A                           push    0000005Ah
// 00403C51  68F8655800                     push    SWC005865F8_AC__Present__Built_in_Display__P
// 00403C56  8D4DE0                         lea ecx,[ebp-20h]
// 00403C59  E8A2060000                     call    SUB_L00404300
// 00403C5E  8B75E0                         mov esi,[ebp-20h]
// 00403C61  8BCE                           mov ecx,esi
// 00403C63  E888DAFFFF                     call    SUB_L004016F0
// 00403C68  C6870005000001                 mov byte ptr [edi+00000500h],01h
// 00403C6F  BF01000000                     mov edi,00000001h
// 00403C74                           L00403C74:
// 00403C74  83C6F0                         add esi,FFFFFFF0h
// 00403C77  C745FCFFFFFFFF                 mov dword ptr [ebp-04h],FFFFFFFFh
// 00403C7E  8D460C                         lea eax,[esi+0Ch]
// 00403C81  83C9FF                         or  ecx,FFFFFFFFh
// 00403C84  F0                             lock
// 00403C85  0FC108                         xadd    [eax],ecx
// 00403C88  49                             dec ecx
// 00403C89  85C9                           test    ecx,ecx
// 00403C8B  7F08                           jg  L00403C95
// 00403C8D  8B0E                           mov ecx,[esi]
// 00403C8F  56                             push    esi
// 00403C90  8B11                           mov edx,[ecx]
// 00403C92  FF5204                         call    [edx+04h]
// 00403C95                           L00403C95:
// 00403C95  8BC7                           mov eax,edi
// 00403C97  8B4DF4                         mov ecx,[ebp-0Ch]
// 00403C9A  64890D00000000                 mov fs:[00000000h],ecx
// 00403CA1  59                             pop ecx
// 00403CA2  5F                             pop edi
// 00403CA3  5E                             pop esi
// 00403CA4  8B4DF0                         mov ecx,[ebp-10h]
// 00403CA7  33CD                           xor ecx,ebp
// 00403CA9  E80A5F1200                     call    SUB_L00529BB8
// 00403CAE  8BE5                           mov esp,ebp
// 00403CB0  5D                             pop ebp
// 00403CB1  C3                             retn
```

I found a corresponding portion of the assembly in the hex dump. I changed 75 07 to 75 33 to try to get the program to skip throwing an error and continue below that point. That was my thought anyway. The .exe won't start now. I'm going to consider this as answered, because Jester did tell me how to find a corresponding section of assembly code in the hex dump.

```
// 00403C0A  7433                           jz  L00403C3F
// 00403C0C  8D4DE0                         lea ecx,[ebp-20h]
// 00403C0F  83F812                         cmp eax,00000012h
// 00403C12  7507                           jnz L00403C1B
```

```
//00 EB 22 E8 F8 FA FF FF 85 C0 74 33 8D 4D E0 83 
//F8 12 75 07 68 B8 62 58 00 EB 05 68 E8 63 58 00
```

Ok. New development. I changed everything back to normal then updated 74 33 to 75 33. The program appears to skip the monitor check, but it's getting hung on another check. I think this is progress though.

I modified one or two more 74's to 75's or vice versa. The update ran and claimed it successfully completed, but the dock is still bricked.

Comment: Simplest is to do a search for a unique part in hex. Sophisticated is to map virtual addresses to file offsets using metadata.

Comment: Which unique part would you choose to search for? I have tried converting portions of the assembly language to hex using an online utility, but the output is no where to be found in the hex dump as an exact match. I have read about jz/ jnz and their opcodes. I can find what I believe are opcodes scattered through the hex dump, but I don't have the experience to make heads or tails of it.

Comment: There is nothing to convert, the hex is printed in the dump. I'd try the `68 F8 1B 55 00` for a start. PS: of course your tool (that I am not familiar with) may also have an option to directly tell you the file offset.

Comment: Wow. That is the missing piece for the moment. Now it is very clear what that second column in the disassembled code represents. I'll try to run with this.

Comment: This is a PE, it's not a firmware, you can use CFF Explorer to map the (R)VA to file offsets. Or just do "address" - 0x401000 + (either 0x1000 or 0x400). These are commonly used values, not 100% bulletproof.